# Download page with Knockout bindings via PhantomJs

Tags: c#, knockout.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to parse a page on Microsoft Virtual Academy with PhantomJs. For instance [this one](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/virtualizing-managing-sql-server-microsoft-cloud-platform-8871?l=Vtt8tR02_2904984382). I am able to load it (see [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yorimoy2gact4d/course.html?dl=0)) but in the downloaded source code I don't see the description of the course or its duration.

To download a page I've used next approach: https://gist.github.com/DotNetNerd/5635371.

```
public string Grab(string url)
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        FileName = Config.PhantomJSPath,
        Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\\{1}\" {2}", Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName, "index.js", url)
    };

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return output;
}
```

and IndexJs

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
};
page.open(system.args[1]);
```

Should I configure phantomjs to wait until binding will take effect or PhantomJs simply doesn't support it?

Comment: Never tried using PhantomJS directly but try using Selenium's PhantomJSDriver. The Source code that you are downloading won't show what you expect since the virtual academy website is creating the site via javascript. Using Selenium, you can get most details on the site using its methods.

Comment: I've used PhantomJs to download page where content was populated with JS and it worked fine. But I haven't tried it with knockout. Do you have a successful experience with downloading such pages with Selenium's PhantomJsDriver?

Comment: `in the downloaded source code I don't see the description of the course or its duration.` It is probably downloaded by AJAX.

Comment: @Artiom Yes. Great tools for navigating, testing, and web scraping sites.

Comment: @SILENT did you mean GhostDriver (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) as Selenium's PhantomJSDriver?

Comment: @Artiom Watch this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oCm6S5zGdE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to wait for 5s after the page was loaded. It doesn't guarantee that everything will load by this time but worked for me.

Index.js was updated to:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
}, 5000);

};
page.open(system.args[1]);
```